# How to perform math operations only in lines with numbers?

Tags: perl, substitution

I have a file where only some lines start with numbers. I want to perform simple math operations in those lines.

For example, say those lines are in this format:

```
010 - 0050 - 20500
```

and I want to add 100 only to the second number:

```
010 - 0150 - 20500
```

Is `perl` the best tool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# 5.10+
perl -pe's/^[0-9]+ - \K([0-9]+)/ sprintf "%04d", $1 + 100 /e'

# Backwards compatible
perl -pe's/^([0-9]+ - )([0-9]+)/ $1 . sprintf "%04d", $2 + 100 /e'
```

Usage:

```
perl -pe'...' file      # From file
perl -pe'...' <file     # From STDIN
perl -i~ -pe'...' file  # Modifying in place with backup
perl -i -pe'...' file   # Modifying in place without backup
```

If you prefer a standlone program, the above is simply equivalent to:

```
while (<>) {
   s/^[0-9]+ - \K([0-9]+)/ sprintf "%04d", $1 + 100 /e;
   print;
}
```

It doesn't mess with any lines except the ones you want to change, and it doesn't mess with any other part of the line like the other solutions are doing.

Comment: The [`\K`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Look-Around-Assertions) escape is only valid on [5.10.0](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5100delta.html#%5cK-escape) or newer Perls.

Answer (score 1):

In Perl this is not too difficult.

```
open my $fh, "<", "filename" or die $!;
while (<$fh>) {
    if ($_ =~ /(\d{3}) - (\d{4}) - (\d{5})/) {
        printf "%.3d - %.4d - %.5d\n", $1, $2 + 100, $3;
    } else {
        print $_;
    }
}
```

Comment: I was screamed at for not using `open(my $fh, "<", "filename");` here recently (bad style; has possible security implications in some other uses).

Comment: @vonbrand to be honest, I have never seen it used that way. I hope I fixed it correctly. (And thanks for the hint!)

Comment: Looks fine now (but note that it isn't natural to me yet!).

Comment: The syntax and lexical file handles were introduced 13 years ago (in the last millennium). Not using global vars? Good thing. Not allowing arbitrary code execution? Good thing.

Answer (score 1):

In Python:

```
fp = open("yourfile.txt","r")
for line in fp.readlines():
    for i in range(0,9):
        if line.startswith(str(i)):
            elems = line.split(" - ")
            elems[1] = "0"+str(int(elems[1]+100))
            whatyouneed = " - ".join(elems)
```

Whatyouneed contains the desired result. Please excuse any errors, as I have no means to test that code. Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

Perl is a good tool for something like that, yes. But if it is the best tool for *your* case depends on a lot of other considerations:

- Is this a one-shot job, or will you have to do the same (or similar) things regularly?
- Do you know Perl already? Are there other, similar languages (like Python or perhaps awk), that you are already confortable with?
- How large is the file? (If it's just 5 lines, do it by hand!)

Learning  a new language is never a total loss, even if you don't expect to use it regularly.

Comment: This job is one-time, but similar problems appear often. The file is big. I know `sed`. But manipulating numbers like this is something that it is bad at. I suppose `awk` can do it too, but I don't know how to tell it to "return lines normally, and only edit those lines as I say" like in this case.